# Keychain does not sync all Keychain items across devices

Tags: macos, icloud, password, keychain

The Keychain application on my Macbook only syncs the "iCloud Keychain" items with my other Apple devices, which I guess is somewhat the point of "iCloud Keychain", specifically the passwords that are saved from Safari.

I am unable to sync all the other keychain items and store them in my iCloud, like "encrypted volume passwords" and the keychain items that I have manually added to the Keychain application. I would like to sync all my Keychain items available with iCloud. Is this possible? Or, is this not a feature by design?

Pardon me if this is a duplicate question but I have not been able to find any questions on this site regarding this problem.

Comment: what would you like to sync it with? another Mac ?

Comment: Yes, another mac, like my iMac or any Apple device connected to the same iCloud account. My requirement is that I do have a lot of passwords on my Keychain that are not in the "iCloud" section. But every time I do a clean install of the OS (which I do every 6 months), and log back in with my iCloud account, only the "iCloud Keychain Items" are retrieved, all the other keychain items are lost and I have to re-enter them one by one by "Creating new Keychain item".

Comment: Try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362917/force-a-sync-of-icloud-keychain-from-ios-to-macos/425696#425696