# Force a sync of iCloud Keychain from iOS to macOS?

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, keychain

My passwords on my iCloud Keychain on my MacBook and iPhone are out of sync. There are several new passwords on each device that aren't present on the other. Following a Google search, I logged out of iCloud on my laptop and logged in again but that didn't work.

Is there any way I can force a sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can force an iCloud keychain sync as per Apple Support document, [Get help with iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/HT203783#sync)

> ### If you want to sync iCloud Keychain with other devices
>
> Make sure that your new device has [the latest version of iOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204) and the [latest version of macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201541). Then, make sure that your device is on a Wi-Fi or cellular network. If the connection appears strong, try these steps:
>
> 1. Turn off iCloud Keychain on all devices.
> 2. Turn on iCloud Keychain on the device that has the most up-to-date keychain items.
> 3. Turn on iCloud Keychain on your other devices. They will be updated with your new iCloud Keychain.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above advice worked for me. Here's what did:

1. Shut off iCloud Keychain in Settings (untick the box).
2. Open KeychainAccess.app.
3. Open preferences with `<cmd+,>` keys.
4. Click `Reset My Default Keychains` **You will lose your local keychain data stored on your computer. But if you're trying to sync with iCloud, the iCloud Keychain is the one you ultimately want**.
5. Sign out and sign back in, go to settings, turn on iCloud Keychain (tick the box). Give it a minute to update.
6. Logout and log back in one more time.

I had to play around with this several times. But I think what happens is the forced refresh needs a new login keychain in `~\Library\Keychain`

NOTE: **Don't touch the encrypted (?) folder with a bunch of random letters.** But I did delete the .db files several times while testing. Now my keychain access works!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had very little luck with the various Apple approved methods of solving this issue. Nothing would appear on my Macbook’s iCloud Keychain even after very elaborate tricks to turn iCloud Keychain off and on.

What did work was that in frustration I airdropped a single web site password from my iPhone to my Macbook. Subsequently every password appeared in iCloud Keychain on my Mac and subsequent passwords synced over iCloud. (Like the very password saved on this site I just made on my iPhone 5 minutes ago synced over iCloud to the MacBook soon thereafter).

I don’t know why this worked or if it will work for others but worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that resolved the problem without the need to log out or change passwords.

**Method 1:**

1. On the device where your passwords are up-to-date (e.g., Mac), add a new password to ensure data refresh.
2. Check on the other device to confirm if the passwords have been updated.

**Method 2: (Detailed Steps)**

1. On the device with outdated passwords (e.g., iPhone), go to Settings > iCloud > Keychain & Passwords, and turn off synchronization. Then, shut down the device.
2. Repeat the same steps on the device with up-to-date passwords.
3. After restarting the up-to-date device, activate Keychain & Passwords in Settings > iCloud, then add a temporary new password (e.g., username: test, password: test) to trigger synchronization.
4. Open the outdated device, activate Keychain & Passwords in Settings > iCloud, and check if the passwords have been updated.

This process is generally applicable to all iCloud applications. Following these steps resolved my Keychain synchronization issue.