# Why is my iCloud Keychain not syncing my passwords?

Tags: macos, icloud, password, data-synchronization, keychain

I just reinstalled a fresh copy of macOS Catalina (10.15.2) and set up iCloud with keychain turned in the iCloud settings. However, my Mac did not sync my WiFi networks or Safari passwords from other devices, when iCloud keychain was enabled for those devices. I have 2-factor authentication enabled. I also tried resetting my keychain by disabling it on all my devices and then re-enabling 1 by 1. I also tried signing in and out of iCloud and tried resetting my keychain by opening the Keychain Access app on my mac. How do I fix this issue?

[iCloud Keychain refuses to setup on Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367277/icloud-keychain-refuses-to-setup-on-catalina) answers here didn't help me. I didn't get the ""Upgrade iCloud Security" Prompt either.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210642#macos10141 No fixes for this issue so far.

Comment: Sorry, but none of the solutions that you linked worked for me. I already tried logging in and out of iCloud. I also don't get that "Upgrade iCloud Security Prompt."

Comment: I am using macOS 10.15.2

Comment: Try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362917/force-a-sync-of-icloud-keychain-from-ios-to-macos/425696#425696